# Spring MVC, Binding, multi-select options following validation

Tags: spring-mvc, validation

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have a form that is being validated with JSR 303. After validation fails, the controller returns the form, shows validation errors, and renders the form with the original values. This works fine with all types of form elements except the mutli-select element.

The command object:

```
public class TaskOrder implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   ...

   @XmlTransient
   @ManyToMany
   @<OtherJPAAnnotations...>
   private List<Contractor> subcontractors;

   ...

}
```

Contractor class:

```
public class Contractor implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @<OtherJPAAnnotations...>
   private Integer id;

   @<OtherJPAAnnotations...>
   private String name;

}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="processingPath", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String createNewTaskOrder(@Valid @ModelAttribute TaskOrder taskOrder,
   BindingResult result,
   Model model) {

   ...

   if (!result.hasErrors()) {

      //No binding errors, lots of processing...

   else {

      model.addAllAttributes(result.getModel());
      model.addAttribute(taskOrder);

      model.addAttribute("subs", myDAOInstance.getSubs());

      return this.setupNewTaskOrder(model);

   }

}

@RequestMapping("getFormPath")
public String setupNewTaskOrder(Model model) {

   if (!model.containsAttribute("taskOrder")) {

      TaskOrder taskOrder = new TaskOrder();
      taskOrder.setId(0);
      model.addAttribute(taskOrder);

   }

   return "_n/admin/taskOrder/new";

}
```

The form:

```
<form:form commandName="taskOrder" action="processPath">

   ...

   <form:select path="subcontractors">
      <form:options items="${subs}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
   </form:select>

   ...

</form>
```

When I open an existing "TaskOrder" with the same form, the values are selected in the "subcontractors" multi-select.

However, trying to add a new "TaskOrder", when it returns from validation the values aren't selected. I know that the selected values are being attached to the model and returned, but just not being selected in the select element.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Based on a similar behavior that I have seen before - does your Contractor class have an equals method, can you please add it and see if you are still have the same problem.

Comment: @wannabecode: could you show what is rendered as HTML, in place of the form:select tag? I think the problem relies there..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Biju...you were correct!

For those who may stumble across this issue, I added the "EqualsUtil" class described here to my project:
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17

Then added the following method to my Contractor class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

   if (this == o) return true;
   if (!(o instanceof Contractor)) return false;

   Contractor c = (Contractor) o;

   //Here I ignore the other properties since "id" and "name" are what
   //I'm primarily concerned with...
   return EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.name, c.name) &&
        EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.id, c.id);

}
```